# checking time in c

Tags: c, time

I want to check to see if a process is still running - if so update the current time - if not return out of the function bc process has died...if the process hasnt died and stop limit has passed then you exit out the loop but it doesnt seem that currTime is updating...

```
int g_iStopLimit = 30; //declared globally


/////process gets signaled to be killed but may take a while to close cleanly...

time_t startTime, currTime;
time(&startTime);
currTime = time(NULL);

do //check to see if process gets killed
{
    if (kill(g_StatusInstance[i].pid, 0) == 0)  //some global array
    {
        currTime = time(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

}while(currTime >= (startTime + g_iStopLimit));


////send a stronger signal and call kill - use recursion and call function over until it kills it
```

Comment: What does "kill()" do? If kill always returns 0 and currTime is < (startTime + g_iStopLimit), then it'll loop forever.

Comment: kill checks to see if the process is still running...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(currTime >= (startTime + g_iStopLimit));
```

should be

```
while(currTime <= (startTime + g_iStopLimit));
```

Originally, `startTime` and `currTime` are almost identical, so unless the `kill` takes an unusual amount of time, the loop ends after the first iteration.

Comment: feel so extra stupid for asking that - i was so caught up the fact that when i printed the time out it wasnt changing that i didnt even realize